# Array sent to to PHP through AJAX not array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I sent an array to the server using AJAX:

```
$(document).on("click", "#create_qr_codes_pdf", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var qr_array = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $("#qrcode_top img").length; i++) {
            qr_array.push($('#code' +i+' img').attr('src'));
        }
        $.ajax({            
            url: 'server/qr_id_create.php?create_qr_codes_pdf',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {qr_array: qr_array},
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
                window.open("server/qr_id_create.php?create_qr_codes_pdf");
            }
        });
    });
```

In PHP I am receiving the array like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['create_qr_codes_pdf'])) {
        $qr_images = $_POST['qr_array'];

        require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
        require_once('tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php'); 
        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
        $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 009');
        $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
        $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
        $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 009', PDF_HEADER_STRING);
        $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
        $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
        $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
        $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
        $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
        $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
        $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
        if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
            require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
            $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
        }

        $pdf->AddPage();

        foreach ($qr_images as $img) {
            $img = preg_replace('/^[^,]*,\s*/', '', $img);
            $img = base64_decode($img);
            $pdf->Image('@'.$img);
            $pdf->AddPage();
        }

        $pdf->Output('qr_codes.pdf', 'I');
}
```

Here is how I test the array in php:

```
if (isset($_GET['create_qr_codes_pdf'])) {
    $qr_images = $_POST['qr_array'];
    if (is_array($qr_images)) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

However, I keep getting an `Undefined index` error with the `qr_array` in php on line (in this case) 2.
When I check if the array is an actual array it returns 'false'.

```
var_dump($qr_images);
```

Returns the following result:

```
array(1) {
  ["qr_array"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4658) "data:image/png;base64,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"
    [1]=>
    string(4586) "data:image/png;base64,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"
  }
}
```

However, if I get the output in a new window as specified in Jquery on AJAX success: `window.open("server/qr_id_create.php?create_qr_codes_pdf");` I get a `var_dump($qr_images)` result `array(0) { }`...

Can anyone please identify the issue here? I am pulling out my hair!

Comment: I'm assuming some typo here, you  `print_r` `$qr_array` but `is_array` `$qr_images`. The array exists, but the actual key might not, how are you iterating it?

Comment: Yes so sorry that should also be $qr_images! Ill do an edit!

Comment: You can test with `gettype($qr_images)`. About the `undefined index` run `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Please see my update!

Comment: Where is your undefined index then? It works.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Which line is the error?

Comment: I promise you, this is the actual error I am getting: `Notice: Undefined index: qr_array in C:\xampp\htdocs\*\qr_id_create.php on line 115` The new window output result strangely enough states `array(0) { }`. Something is very weird....

Comment: I can't see your code, I don't know the code of qr_id_create.php neither what's in line 115. Update your question keeping in mind that we can't see you code. Post all relevant code here.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I made some changes. At this stage I am just trying to find out why my array won't work...

Comment: I think I understood you problem here. After success, you don't have `$_POST` data anymore, cause you have a `GET` request.

Comment: @Cool, that makes sense... How can one fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you have POST data:

```
$.ajax({            
    url: 'server/qr_id_create.php?create_qr_codes_pdf', <--HERE YOU HAVE POST DATA
    type: 'POST',
    data: {qr_array: qr_array},
    success: function(data) { 
        window.open("server/qr_id_create.php?create_qr_codes_pdf");  <--HERE YOU DON'T HAVE POST DATA
    }
});
```

So, you need to check when is a POST request with:

```
if(isset($_POST['qr_array'])) {
    //the code for ajax request
    $qr_images = $_POST['qr_array'];
    if (is_array($qr_images)) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
} else {
    //the code you expect to run after the request is successfull
    echo 'request success';
}
```

Comment: Thanks this all makes sense, the only problem I have is the `$qr_images` variable that I want to use after the request is successful?

Comment: No, unless you store it somewhere, in database, file or user session (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: I have added a section of what I am trying to achieve in the end. Are you saying that I won't be able to achieve it this way?

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way you send JSON format, not in array

Comment: This is not an answer, just your opinion. It will be better if you try to solve the OP problem with some code.